# Magento index page loads but 404 errors on all others

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

Currently I am struggling with the categories and products showing 404 errors when I navigate away from the working home page.

I was able to install Magento and I am using a copy of an existing working site.  The purpose is to use this new site as my dev sandbox. I am using Magento 1.11.  This is also a multiple store site.

Things I have tried:
Reindex the Catalog URL Rewrite, this unfortunately never completes.

To try and solve this I have deleted all the lock files and then I have also deleted all the entries in the `core_url_rewrite` table.

I have also changed the Base URL in the `core_config_data` table to my new URL.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have but it seems that Reindexing the Catalog URL Rewrites never completes.

Comment: you can try from command line: `php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall`

Comment: add index.php between your base url and your request params, e.g. `http://site.com/index.php/cms/page/view/id/home` vs. `http://site.com/cms/page/view/id/home`

Comment: benmarks, that worked...  Why did that work? Also what do i have to do to make sure that is included?  Do I need to add that to the RewriteBase in the .htaccess file?

Comment: You are probably missing this from your VirtualHost configuration (assuming Apache): `<Directory /path/to/site/> AllowOverride All </Directory>`

Comment: Need to enable mod_rewrite? Every time I've had off-home-page 404's was because SEO Use Server Rewrites was set to Yes, but the DSO module wasn't loaded. There also should be two lines: **Options +FollowSymLinks** and **RewriteEngine on** in your Magento root .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

Just like [Fiasco Labs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722112/fiasco-labs) said, you probably turned on URL Rewriting:

`System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Search Engine Optimizations -> Use Server Rewrites` but don't have `mod_rewrite` Installed/Enabled.

Either Install/Enable it on your host, or just turn the server rewrites `off`.

Another reason, if you HAVE `mod_rewrite` Installed/Enabled, you might be missing `.htaccess` file in your Magento root.

Comment: he means www.example.com/admin too]

Answer (score 0):

even with mod_rewrite enabled, the error can be a misconfiguration of apache. Have a look at etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file. Find the part where  is defined (standard Apache config dir). You should find:

> AllowOverride All

If there is a

> AllowOverride None

Change it to All and the magic happens. Then restart Apache with:

> sudo service httpd restart